# массивы в javascript node js. как работать с { }

Tags: javascript, массивы, node.js

впервые столкнулся с такой проблемой) просто не могу правильно вытащить данные из массива; если до этого массивы у меня всегда выглядели

```
data:[
arra,
array,
array]
```

и можно легко вытащить data[0] = arra;
то вот у меня пример

```
{
    "server_time": 1530797845,
    "pairs": {
        "ltc_btc": {
            "decimal_places": 8,
            "max_price": 10000,
            "fee": 0.2
        },
        "nmc_btc": {
            "decimal_places": 8,
            "max_price": 10000,
            "fee": 0.2
        },
etc...
```

мне надо получить названия всех пар(pairs): ltc_btc, nmc_btc, ...
У меня не получается сделать таким образом massive.pairs[i]
помогите нубу)

может надо как то по-другому спарсить данные

```
request({url:url, json:true},  function(err, res, body){
```

мб в этом месте что то изменить; 
или просто есть, что то элементарное что мне поможет)

Comment: Элементарно `massive.pairs.ltc_btc`. У вас `massive.pairs` - не массив. Используйте его как обычный объект.

Comment: так у меня 100 названий )  суть вытащить названия )

Comment: `Object.keys(massive.pairs)`

Comment: вот, спасибо, добрый человек) не знал о таком способе)